# c# Winforms - How to change a vertical MenuStrip navigation to be more user friendly? (intuitive)

Tags: c#, winforms, arrow-keys, menustrip

I have a vertical MenuStrip similar to this one:

Vertical MenuStrip Example

[image: Vertical MenuStrip Example]

(LayoutStyle = VerticalStackWithOverflow, Dock = Left) and I need to change the way that the arrow keys work inside the menu because they act like the MenuStrip was horizontal (right and left arrow keys to navigate between items) and I need that it acts as a vertical Menu (up and down arrow keys to navigate between items).

It's ok if you don't give me the exact way to do it but at least I need some help to change those arrow keys events if it is possible.

If you want to recreate the situation just create a MDI form and use the properties that I mentioned, you will notice that the navigation doesn't feel natural for the "parent" items.

I hope you can help me and also other people that might have the same problem, thank you!